# PackageInstallStatus after downloading the apk always returns to PendingUserAction Xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin, apk, installation-package

I am trying to download an apk in my app. After successfully downloading the apk. I am trying to get the PackageInstallationStatus. But each time it is returning to PendingUserAction.

Device version: 8.0

Here is my pending intent that is starting an activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Listener as Activity, Listener.GetType());                                                                                                                           
intent.SetAction(PackageInstalledAction);

var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(Listener as Activity, 0,intent,0);

var statusReceiver = pendingIntent.IntentSender;

session.Commit(statusReceiver);
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use BroadcastReceiver for `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` where you get package name using `packageName = intent.getData().getEncodedSchemeSpecificPart();`